# SplashScene not centered

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am trying out AndEngine and cannot work out why my splashscreen is not centered in the device - see the image below.
I have set a default size for the device `(800, 480)` and placed the splash at `camera.getWidth() / 2`. It seems like the corner of my splash hits the center pretty spot on but I want the center of the splash to be centered - makes sense?

[image: Screen:]

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.caspe.getmeout;

import org.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.andengine.engine.LimitedFPSEngine;
import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.handler.timer.ITimerCallback;
import org.andengine.engine.handler.timer.TimerHandler;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.WakeLockOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;    
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity {
    private ResourcesManager resourcesManager;
    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
    private Camera camera;

    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(800, 480), this.camera);
        engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsMusic(true).setNeedsSound(true);
        engineOptions.setWakeLockOptions(WakeLockOptions.SCREEN_ON);
        return engineOptions;
    }

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine(EngineOptions pEngineOptions) {
        return new LimitedFPSEngine(pEngineOptions, 60);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateResources(OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback) throws Exception {
        ResourcesManager.prepareManager(mEngine, this, camera, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        resourcesManager = ResourcesManager.getInstance();
        pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback) throws IOException {
        SceneManager.getInstance().createSplashScene(pOnCreateSceneCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene, OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws IOException {
        mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(2f, new ITimerCallback() {
            public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
                mEngine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
                // load menu resources, create menu scene
                // set menu scene using scene manager
                // disposeSplashScene();
            }
        }));
        pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();
    }

}
```

And the code for Splash:

```
package com.example.caspe.getmeout;

import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.opengl.util.GLState;
import com.example.caspe.getmeout.BaseScene;
import com.example.caspe.getmeout.SceneManager.SceneType

public class SplashScene extends BaseScene {

    private Sprite splash;

    @Override
    public void createScene() {
        splash = new Sprite(0,0, resourcesManager.splash_region, vbom) {
            @Override
            protected void preDraw(GLState pGLState, Camera pCamera) {
                super.preDraw(pGLState, pCamera);
                pGLState.enableDither();
            }
        };

        splash.setScale(1.5f);
        splash.setPosition(camera.getWidth() / 2, camera.getHeight() / 2);
        attachChild(splash);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackKeyPressed() {
    }

    @Override
    public SceneType getSceneType() {
        return SceneType.SCENE_SPLASH;
    }

    @Override
    public void disposeScene() {
        splash.detachSelf();
        splash.dispose();
        this.detachSelf();
        this.dispose();
    }

}
```

Please let me know if you need more code than this.
I am not directly seeking a working piece of code but more where my error is so I can use my braincells and work it out - I have just stared myself blind here.

Comment: I am following this guide btw: http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tutorial---part-5.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
splash.setPosition(camera.getWidth() / 2, camera.getHeight() / 2);
```

That is not enough. Your splash is actually centered correctly: the top left corner is in the center.

What you need is to subtract the half width and height of the splash from the position, too.

```
// untested code
splash.setPosition(camera.getWidth() / 2 - splash.getWidth() / 2, camera.getHeight() / 2 - splash.getHeight() / 2);
```

Comment: I have been thinking this. I was looking into my splash and how to devide it into 4 equal pieces in order to get the center. I'll try out and test my luck. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually, your untested code worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!